# What's the measure of the $\angle ABD$ in the triangle below?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: In triangle $ABC$ the cevian $BD$ and the median $CM$ are drawn; the angle bisector of $\angle BCM$ bisects $BD$ at $N$.
.Calculate $\angle ABD$ if $AD=2, DC= 1$ and $BC=\sqrt3$
(Resolution by geometry if possible - Answer $15^o$)

My progress:
[image]

$AM = BM\\BN=DN$

$TH. Menelao:S\triangle AEC-DB:\\: AD.CN.EB = CD.EN.AB \implies 2.CN.EB = EN.AB\\
Th. Menelao:S\triangle AMC-DB:\\AD.CF.MB = CD.FM.AB \implies CF = FM\\
Th. Menelao:\triangle ABD-MC:\\AM.BE.DE=MB.DE.AC \implies BE = 3DE\\
Th. Menelao:\triangle ABD-NC:\\ \implies AN = 3BN$

I'm not seeing any more similarities being applied...

Comment: What does "the angle $BCM$ bisects $BD$ at $N$" mean? Did you mean "The angle bisector of $\angle BCM$ cuts $BD$ at $N$"?

Comment: If you want to say the angle bisector of $\angle BCM$ bisects $BD$ at $N$ then the answer should be $30^\circ$ and not $15^\circ$. Please fix the question.

Comment: @MathLover    bisects =  to divide something into two, usually equal, parts therfore $CE$ divides the segment $BD$ into two equal parts. as well as trisect
: to divide into three usually equal parts (Merriam Webater)

Comment: @IEatPorkEverySingleDay  See the comment to Math..

Comment: Please read your question carefully and edit. What does it mean that _angle $BCM$ bisects $BD$_? Do you mean $CE$ bisects $BD$? Then say so. Is $CE$ angle bisector of $BCM$? Then say so.

Comment: @MathLover  I believe the question is correct...my mistake was in trying to solve it and saying that CE is angle bisector...it is not...the verb bisect exists and I have already posted the meaning...S
If you have a better suggestion you can say that I make the correction.

Comment: @MathLover If you used the correct concept of bisect and got $30^o$ it is possible that the answer is wrong because the book has many

Comment: @MathLover I corrected the drawing.

Comment: Thanks but "angle BCM bisects $BD$" is very ambiguous. That is my feedback. If you want to edit, it should state that angle bisector of $\angle BCM$ bisects $BD$ at $N$. I cannot think of another meaning.

Comment: @MathLover edited as per your suggestion..I found two more relationships $BE = 3DE$ and $AN =3BN$

Comment: Please type *words* outside `$…$`. Also proofread your post before or just after posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

$15^\circ$ is not the correct answer. GeoGebra shows the same.

In $\triangle ABD$, traversal $EC$ intersects $BA$ and $BD$ internally and $AD$ externally. Applying Menelaus's theorem,

$ \displaystyle \frac{AC}{CD} \cdot \frac{DN}{NB} \cdot \frac{BE}{EA} = 1 \implies EA = 3 BE$

Or, $EM + MA = 3 BM - 3 EM$.
As $BM = MA$, $BM =2 EM \implies E$ is midpoint of $BM$.

As $CE$ is also the angle bisector, $BC = CM = \sqrt3$ and $CE \perp AB$

If $BE = x$, applying Pythagoras in $\triangle AEC$ and $\triangle BEC$,

$CE^2 = BC^2 - x^2 = AC^2 - (3x)^2 \implies 3 - x^2 = 9 - 9 x^2$

$ \displaystyle x = \frac{\sqrt3}{2}, AB = 2 \sqrt3$

As $BC = CM = MB$, $\triangle BCM$ is equilateral triangle and $\angle ABC = 60^\circ$.

Now given $AD:DC = BA:BC$, $BD$ is angle bisector of $\angle ABC$.

$\therefore \angle ABD = 30^\circ$

(As a side note, $\triangle ACB$ is right triangle with $\angle ACB = 90^\circ$)

Comment: Thanks for the resolution but I have some questions:
My geogebra figure meets all the requirements..why is it wrong?
$EM$ is midpoint of $BM$ (ok) but why $CE$ is angle bisector? Triangle $BCM$ would need to be isosceles and need to be demonstrated..

Comment: @petaarantes did we not edit the question to say that the angle bisector of $\angle BCM$ intersects $BD$ at $N$? As you can see yourself, both your diagram and my diagram meet all requirements. So there must be additional condition for a unique solution and that is why $CE$ being angle bisector makes it a unique solution.

Comment: You are absolutely right....I have reviewed the original question which is in Spanish and it is mentioned " angle bisector bisect $BD$ in $N$..I was mistaken and was not considering that $CE$ is angle bisector but only a segment that divides $BD$ into two equal segments...Gratitude.
Thanks for the explanations(my drawing therefore is not correct)